# Insert Content of Layout XML into ID-specific View

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, insert

I am currently working on a little game to practice my programming skills with Android Studio.

In my Java file I load my desired data from a MySQL data base. 
Now I want to display a layout from another XML file with TextViews, ImageViews, etc. (e.g. displayItemsBlock.xml) in an existing "insert" Layout/View and apply my variable values to the TextViews.

http://abload.de/img/problemnouc6.jpg

I search for a function like this:

- Define InsertPoint by ID (e.g. LinearLayout id 'insertPoint')
- Define which xml layout will be placed into the InsertPoint
- Change the Contents of the inserted xml layout with setText somehow.

In the end it should be possible to add more of these Views dynamically and change the contents individually.

I hope you understand what my problem is.
Thank you

Regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but somewhat involved / difficult.

The issue is that in a 'normal' Android application, the layout xml files are compiled into a binary form. It's this binary form that is used at runtime, e.g. with an Inflater.

So, to make this work, you'd have to parse the xml file yourself, and then programmatically create the appropriate views and add them to the desired "parent" views.

As far as I know, there is nothing in the Android libraries that will do this for you. You may want to look around to see if there is a third-party library to handle any of part of this.

P.S. I hope that you're not really accessing MySQL directly from your Android app  as shown in your drawing - you do have a service / api in front of that, don't you?

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I will then create all the views dynamically without xml. And to load data from MySQL I use AsyncTask and JSON Parse including a web api.